# Python script will not run on new machine

Tags: python

I have several Python scripts that I've created and use on a daily basis. I moved the scripts to another machine to run as scheduled tasks. 2 of the 3 run but the third simply will not.  No errors are presented. Looks like the python window opens for a split second and then it closes.  This script is supposed to create files but they are never created.
Any idea what might be happening and how I can start to find a fix?  Thanks!

This works:

```
import os, time, sys

def open_program(path_name):
    os.startfile(path_name)

def close_program(p):
    p.terminate()

try:
    myRumba = "C:\Rumba\Desktops\A-Window.rdps"
    open_program(myRumba)

    time.sleep(20)
    os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM RumbaPage.exe')
    os._exit(0)
except OSError:
    print(OSError)
else:
    print('Rumba closed')
```

But this does not...

```
import os
from datetime import date, datetime

with open("C:\\Data\\Downloads\\test.txt", "w") as TestFile:
    today = date.today()
    TestFile.write(str(today))
```

Comment: Execute it via command line instead of double-clicking the script from the file explorer.

Comment: Did you code it to store it in a specific path on your previous machine. If so the path may not be existent on your new machine.

Comment: I double-checked that the directories needed do exist.

Comment: I am able to open the file and run through the IDLE without any errors. The files are created as expected.  But i need this to run as a scheduled task using the py file, just like the others.  Any reason why this wouldn't work by double-clicking the py file itself?

Comment: If you are able to successfully run the script from the command line, you can create another Python script whose sole purpose is to run the troublesome script, as if from the command line.  You can make the new script print "Hello, World!" (or some other sign of life) to make sure it's really running.  (I don't recommend this as a permanent solution, but rather as a step to help you troubleshoot what's wrong.)

Comment: can you show the line of code used to create the files? add some code if you want real help.

Comment: From your code, I see nothing that shouldn't work on Python 3.6 . So here's a recommendation: In the code that works, put this line in: print(sys.version) . This should tell you if you're really running Python 3.6 or if you're running another version you never even considered (such as Python 2.7). It's worth a shot.  (This comment was added down below as well.)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much information for anyone know exactly what's going on, so unless we get more information, you'll have to do some troubleshooting on your own.

Here's a suggestion on how to start troubleshooting:

Take the script that's giving you trouble, and make an identical copy of it, then run the copy.  Does the problem still happen?  If not, there's something wrong with the script's name and/or path.

If the problem still happens, open the new script in a text editor of your choice, delete all the code, and replace it with:

```
print('Hello, World!')
```

(or some line(s) of code that will let you easily verify that the script is running).  Save the script's changes, but *do not* exit the text editor, as we will soon be CTRL-Z/undoing the code deletion.

If the new script still doesn't run, then there's something wrong with the way the script is being invoked.

But if the new script successfully runs, undo the script's changes (to get the entire script's contents back), then delete all but the first 10% of the script (or main() code), and replace the deleted part with that `print('Hello, World!')` line.  Then save the script, and try running it again.

Now if the script doesn't run, you'll have a smoking gun: Chances are very likely that the problem lies in the first ten percent of the script, and hopefully you should be able to easily find the problem.

But if the script still runs, bring back the next 10% of the script (so that you have 20% of the original script there), and try to run again.

Once again, if it runs, you'll know that your problem lies in that second 10% of the code.  And if it doesn't it'll probably be in the remaining 80%, which you can narrow down by bringing the original script back 10% at a time.

---

Unfortunately, I can't be more specific as to where the problem lies, as I can't see the contents of your scripts.  But at least I can offer the above bug-hunting method, which should (hopefully) narrow down the scope of the error.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I added some code. The machine that is failing to run this script is Python 3.6 but my dev machine is 3.7.  Not sure if that matters.

Comment: @justin26: It very well might.  If your script contains code that was allowed starting in Python 3.7, then it will fail to run if invoked with Python 3.6 .  I wish there were a line to add at the top of a script which says "If not running Python 3.7, fail gracefully with a helpful error message." but I know of nothing that will work 100% of the time.  Instead, you'll get some odd compiler error messages.

Comment: From your code, I see nothing that shouldn't work on Python 3.6 .  So here's a recommendation:  In the code that works, put this line in:  `print(sys.version)` .  This should tell you if you're *really* running Python 3.6 or if you're running another version you never even considered (such as Python 2.7).  It's worth a shot.